# Parsing STDF Files to Compare results

Tags: shell, parsing, scripting

I am new to this site and I would like to get some inputs regarding parsing STDF files.  Generally speaking, I am trying to parse a STDF file to gather only the results (numbers) and not the rest of the line.  If I am able to achieve this, I would then like to compare all the numbers together through a bubble sort or insertion sort and see if any numbers are equal to each other.  I am capable of doing this in C/C++ and Java but I have no experience parsing documents using Scripts.

Could anyone push me in the right direction?  What should I be reading to learn my way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you already using an STDF library?
You did not mention one, so I assume not.

You should find a library you are comfortable with (the list changes over time, but you can find some by Googling or looking at the STDF page on Wikipedia) rather than attempting to parse STDF yourself, unless you have a good reason to recreate the STDF parser wheel.

An STDF file contains many tests.  It generally does not make sense to compare the results for different tests, so I assume you are looking for matching values within the set of results for each test.

I would use your chosen STDF parser to read the value of each test for each part.  Keep a set of the results for each test.  As you read each new result, check the set to see if already exists.  If it does, you have found the case you were looking for, otherwise add the result to the set.